# unable to parse the json in my java program

Tags: java, json

I am trying to decode the json objects into multiple strings.I dont know how to parse the json object.

here is my json string

```
{"page_1":"{\"city\":\"Bangalore\",\"locality\":\"Battarahalli\",\"Name_of_Person\":\"xxx\",\"User_email_address\":\"xxx@gmail.com\",\"user_phone_number\":\"\",\"sub_locality\":\"\",\"street_name\":\"7th Cross Road, Near Reliance Fresh, T.c Palya,\",\"home_plot_no\":\"45\",\"pin_code\":\"560049\",\"project_society_build_name\":\"Sunshine Layout\",\"landmark_reference_1\":\"\",\"landmark_reference_2\":\"\",\"No_of_Schools\":20,\"No_of_Hospitals\":20,\"No_of_Metro\":0,\"No_of_Mall\":11,\"No_of_Park\":10,\"Distance_of_schools\":1.55,\"Distance_of_Hospitals\":2.29,\"Distance_of_Metro\":0,\"Distance_of_Mall\":1.55,\"Distance_of_Park\":2.01,\"lat\":13.0243273,\"lng\":77.7077906,\"ipinfo\":{\"ip\":\"113.193.30.130\",\"hostname\":\"No Hostname\",\"city\":\"\",\"region\":\"\",\"country\":\"IN\",\"loc\":\"20.0000,77.0000\",\"org\":\"AS45528 Tikona Digital Networks Pvt Ltd.\"}}","page_2":"{\"home_type\":\"Flat\",\"area\":\"1350\",\"beds\":\"3 BHK\",\"bath_rooms\":2,\"building_age\":\"1\",\"floors\":2,\"balcony\":2,\"amenities\":\"premium\",\"amenities_options\":{\"gated_security\":\"\",\"physical_security\":\"\",\"cctv_camera\":\"\",\"controll_access\":\"\",\"elevator\":true,\"power_back_up\":\"\",\"parking\":true,\"partial_parking\":\"\",\"onsite_maintenance_store\":\"\",\"open_garden\":\"\",\"party_lawn\":\"\",\"amenities_balcony\":\"\",\"club_house\":\"\",\"fitness_center\":\"\",\"swimming_pool\":\"\",\"party_hall\":\"\",\"tennis_court\":\"\",\"basket_ball_court\":\"\",\"squash_coutry\":\"\",\"amphi_theatre\":\"\",\"business_center\":\"\",\"jogging_track\":\"\",\"convinience_store\":\"\",\"guest_rooms\":\"\"},\"interior\":\"regular\",\"interior_options\":{\"tiles\":true,\"marble\":\"\",\"wooden\":\"\",\"modular_kitchen\":\"\",\"partial_modular_kitchen\":\"\",\"gas_pipe\":\"\",\"intercom_system\":\"\",\"air_conditioning\":\"\",\"partial_air_conditioning\":\"\",\"wardrobe\":\"\",\"sanitation_fixtures\":\"\",\"false_ceiling\":\"\",\"partial_false_ceiling\":\"\",\"recessed_lighting\":\"\"},\"location\":\"regular\",\"location_options\":{\"good_view\":true,\"transporation_hub\":true,\"shopping_center\":\"\",\"hospital\":\"\",\"school\":\"\",\"ample_parking\":\"\",\"park\":\"\",\"temple\":\"\",\"bank\":\"\",\"less_congestion\":\"\",\"less_pollution\":\"\"},\"maintenance\":\"\",\"maintenance_value\":\"\",\"near_by\":{\"school\":\"\",\"hospital\":\"\",\"mall\":\"\",\"park\":\"\",\"metro\":\"\",\"Near_by_school\":\"Little Champ Gurukulam Pre School \\\/ 1.52 km\",\"Near_by_hospital\":\"Suresh Hospital \\\/ 2.16 km\",\"Near_by_mall\":\"LORVEN LEO \\\/ 2.13 km\",\"Near_by_park\":\"SURYA ENCLAIVE \\\/ 2.09 km\"},\"city\":\"Bangalore\",\"locality\":\"Battarahalli\",\"token\":\"344bd4f0fab99b460873cfff6befb12f\"}"}
```

I tried like this

```
String JSON = "{\"page_1\":{\"city\":\"Bangalore\",\"locality\":\"Anekal\",\"Name_of_Person\":\"sas\",\"User_email_address\":\"ddd32@gmail.com\",\"user_phone_number\":\"\",\"sub_locality\":\"\",\"street_name\":\"farahana\",\"home_plot_no\":\"50\",\"pin_code\":\"\",\"project_society_build_name\":\"\",\"landmark_reference_1\":\"\",\"landmark_reference_2\":\"\",\"No_of_Schools\":20,\"No_of_Hospitals\":8,\"No_of_Metro\":1,\"No_of_Mall\":1,\"No_of_Park\":0,\"Distance_of_schools\":2.51,\"Distance_of_Hospitals\":0.43,\"Distance_of_Metro\":2.55,\"Distance_of_Mall\":0.89,\"Distance_of_Park\":0,\"lat\":12.7105259,\"lng\":77.6911295,\"ipinfo\":{\"ip\":\"113.193.30.130\",\"hostname\":\"No Hostname\",\"city\":\"\",\"region\":\"\",\"country\":\"IN\",\"loc\":\"20.0000,77.0000\",\"org\":\"AS45528 Tikona Digital Networks Pvt Ltd.\"}}\n
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(JSON);
String city =  (String) obj.get("city");
System.out.println(city);
```

But it throws error only

```
Expected a ',' or '}' at 711 [character 1 line 2]
```

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: this is the error with parsing. i think you  have missed with the proper json structure check that every '{' and '}' are matching.

Comment: Your initial json string is `{"page_1": "...", "page_2": "..."}` so you can't access city just with 1 JsonObject. You need at least to use `JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(JSON); String page_1 =  (String) obj.get("page_1"); JSONObject page = new JSONObject(page_1); String city =  (String) page.get("city");`

Comment: when I use the above code.it throws following exception.Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.JSONObject cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Answer (score 0):

you use this JSON. because you left a close curly braces:

```
{
    "page_1": {
        "city": "Bangalore",
        "locality": "Anekal",
        "Name_of_Person": "sas",
        "User_email_address": "ddd32@gmail.com",
        "user_phone_number": "",
        "sub_locality": "",
        "street_name": "farahana",
        "home_plot_no": "50",
        "pin_code": "",
        "project_society_build_name": "",
        "landmark_reference_1": "",
        "landmark_reference_2": "",
        "No_of_Schools": 20,
        "No_of_Hospitals": 8,
        "No_of_Metro": 1,
        "No_of_Mall": 1,
        "No_of_Park": 0,
        "Distance_of_schools": 2.51,
        "Distance_of_Hospitals": 0.43,
        "Distance_of_Metro": 2.55,
        "Distance_of_Mall": 0.89,
        "Distance_of_Park": 0,
        "lat": 12.7105259,
        "lng": 77.6911295,
        "ipinfo": {
            "ip": "113.193.30.130",
            "hostname": "No Hostname",
            "city": "",
            "region": "",
            "country": "IN",
            "loc": "20.0000,77.0000",
            "org": "AS45528 Tikona Digital Networks Pvt Ltd."
        }
    }
}
```

you use json pro lint to debug your JSON: The link is
http://pro.jsonlint.com/

```
public class Kunfu {

    public static void main(String a[]) throws JSONException{

        String JSON = "{\"page_1\":{\"city\":\"Bangalore\",\"locality\":\"Anekal\",\"Name_of_Person\":\"sas\",\"User_email_address\":\"ddd32@gmail.com\",\"user_phone_number\":\"\",\"sub_locality\":\"\",\"street_name\":\"farahana\",\"home_plot_no\":\"50\",\"pin_code\":\"\",\"project_society_build_name\":\"\",\"landmark_reference_1\":\"\",\"landmark_reference_2\":\"\",\"No_of_Schools\":20,\"No_of_Hospitals\":8,\"No_of_Metro\":1,\"No_of_Mall\":1,\"No_of_Park\":0,\"Distance_of_schools\":2.51,\"Distance_of_Hospitals\":0.43,\"Distance_of_Metro\":2.55,\"Distance_of_Mall\":0.89,\"Distance_of_Park\":0,\"lat\":12.7105259,\"lng\":77.6911295,\"ipinfo\":{\"ip\":\"113.193.30.130\",\"hostname\":\"No Hostname\",\"city\":\"\",\"region\":\"\",\"country\":\"IN\",\"loc\":\"20.0000,77.0000\",\"org\":\"AS45528 Tikona Digital Networks Pvt Ltd.\"}}}\n";
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(JSON);
                String city =  (String) obj.getJSONObject("page_1").get("city");
                System.out.println(city);
}}
```

**output:**

```
Bangalore
```

**This code is working well. you try it and you add JSON jar**
The jar file link is:
 **http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavajsonjar.htm**

Comment: I am getting the following error .Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["page_1"] not a string.any help??

Comment: hello, nimmy you try it

Answer (score 0):

Can't fit this in comment, but will try to be short:

First thing is that you get `Expected a ',' or '}' at 711 [character 1 line 2]` because you just copied first half of your initial json. Your initial Json looks like this: `{"page_1": "...", "page_2": "..."}`, but json in your code looks like `{"page_1": {...}` and you are missing closing `}`.

If you really need json from your code you have to
1) add closing `}` to the end of String JSON
2) Take `page_1` object first and then take `city` string from it. Here is demo:

```
String JSON = "{\"page_1\":{\"city\":\"Bangalore\",\"locality\":\"Anekal\",\"Name_of_Person\":\"sas\",\"User_email_address\":\"ddd32@gmail.com\",\"user_phone_number\":\"\",\"sub_locality\":\"\",\"street_name\":\"farahana\",\"home_plot_no\":\"50\",\"pin_code\":\"\",\"project_society_build_name\":\"\",\"landmark_reference_1\":\"\",\"landmark_reference_2\":\"\",\"No_of_Schools\":20,\"No_of_Hospitals\":8,\"No_of_Metro\":1,\"No_of_Mall\":1,\"No_of_Park\":0,\"Distance_of_schools\":2.51,\"Distance_of_Hospitals\":0.43,\"Distance_of_Metro\":2.55,\"Distance_of_Mall\":0.89,\"Distance_of_Park\":0,\"lat\":12.7105259,\"lng\":77.6911295,\"ipinfo\":{\"ip\":\"113.193.30.130\",\"hostname\":\"No Hostname\",\"city\":\"\",\"region\":\"\",\"country\":\"IN\",\"loc\":\"20.0000,77.0000\",\"org\":\"AS45528 Tikona Digital Networks Pvt Ltd.\"}}}";
try {
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(JSON);
    JSONObject page_1 = obj.getJSONObject("page_1");
    String city = page_1.getString("city");
    System.out.println(city);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**But** Json in your 1-st string is not the same as in your code. Your initial Json has this format: `{"page_1": "...", "page_2": "..."}` and as you can see, there are strings and not objects for values. So it is a little bit different and here is demo:

```
String JSON = "{\"page_1\":\"{\\\"city\\\":\\\"Bangalore\\\",\\\"locality\\\":\\\"Battarahalli\\\",\\\"Name_of_Person\\\":\\\"xxx\\\",\\\"User_email_address\\\":\\\"xxx@gmail.com\\\",\\\"user_phone_number\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"sub_locality\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"street_name\\\":\\\"7th Cross Road, Near Reliance Fresh, T.c Palya,\\\",\\\"home_plot_no\\\":\\\"45\\\",\\\"pin_code\\\":\\\"560049\\\",\\\"project_society_build_name\\\":\\\"Sunshine Layout\\\",\\\"landmark_reference_1\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"landmark_reference_2\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"No_of_Schools\\\":20,\\\"No_of_Hospitals\\\":20,\\\"No_of_Metro\\\":0,\\\"No_of_Mall\\\":11,\\\"No_of_Park\\\":10,\\\"Distance_of_schools\\\":1.55,\\\"Distance_of_Hospitals\\\":2.29,\\\"Distance_of_Metro\\\":0,\\\"Distance_of_Mall\\\":1.55,\\\"Distance_of_Park\\\":2.01,\\\"lat\\\":13.0243273,\\\"lng\\\":77.7077906,\\\"ipinfo\\\":{\\\"ip\\\":\\\"113.193.30.130\\\",\\\"hostname\\\":\\\"No Hostname\\\",\\\"city\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"region\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"country\\\":\\\"IN\\\",\\\"loc\\\":\\\"20.0000,77.0000\\\",\\\"org\\\":\\\"AS45528 Tikona Digital Networks Pvt Ltd.\\\"}}\",\"page_2\":\"{\\\"home_type\\\":\\\"Flat\\\",\\\"area\\\":\\\"1350\\\",\\\"beds\\\":\\\"3 BHK\\\",\\\"bath_rooms\\\":2,\\\"building_age\\\":\\\"1\\\",\\\"floors\\\":2,\\\"balcony\\\":2,\\\"amenities\\\":\\\"premium\\\",\\\"amenities_options\\\":{\\\"gated_security\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"physical_security\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"cctv_camera\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"controll_access\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"elevator\\\":true,\\\"power_back_up\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"parking\\\":true,\\\"partial_parking\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"onsite_maintenance_store\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"open_garden\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"party_lawn\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"amenities_balcony\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"club_house\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"fitness_center\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"swimming_pool\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"party_hall\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"tennis_court\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"basket_ball_court\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"squash_coutry\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"amphi_theatre\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"business_center\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"jogging_track\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"convinience_store\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"guest_rooms\\\":\\\"\\\"},\\\"interior\\\":\\\"regular\\\",\\\"interior_options\\\":{\\\"tiles\\\":true,\\\"marble\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"wooden\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"modular_kitchen\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"partial_modular_kitchen\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"gas_pipe\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"intercom_system\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"air_conditioning\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"partial_air_conditioning\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"wardrobe\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"sanitation_fixtures\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"false_ceiling\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"partial_false_ceiling\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"recessed_lighting\\\":\\\"\\\"},\\\"location\\\":\\\"regular\\\",\\\"location_options\\\":{\\\"good_view\\\":true,\\\"transporation_hub\\\":true,\\\"shopping_center\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"hospital\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"school\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"ample_parking\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"park\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"temple\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"bank\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"less_congestion\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"less_pollution\\\":\\\"\\\"},\\\"maintenance\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"maintenance_value\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"near_by\\\":{\\\"school\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"hospital\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"mall\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"park\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"metro\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"Near_by_school\\\":\\\"Little Champ Gurukulam Pre School \\\\\\/ 1.52 km\\\",\\\"Near_by_hospital\\\":\\\"Suresh Hospital \\\\\\/ 2.16 km\\\",\\\"Near_by_mall\\\":\\\"LORVEN LEO \\\\\\/ 2.13 km\\\",\\\"Near_by_park\\\":\\\"SURYA ENCLAIVE \\\\\\/ 2.09 km\\\"},\\\"city\\\":\\\"Bangalore\\\",\\\"locality\\\":\\\"Battarahalli\\\",\\\"token\\\":\\\"344bd4f0fab99b460873cfff6befb12f\\\"}\"}";

try {
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(JSON);
    String page_1Str = obj.getString("page_1");
    JSONObject page_1 = new JSONObject(page_1Str);
    String city = page_1.getString("city");
    System.out.println(city);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I am getting the following error .Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["page_1"] not a string.

Comment: @varren: That must be: `String page_1Str = "page_1";
    JSONObject page_1 = new JSONObject(page_1Str);` otherwise it's throwing the error as @Nimmy said: "page_1" is not of type String and `page_1Str` is null therefor, causing the next error.

Comment: @AxelAmthor @Nimmy i'm just trying to explain that there are **2 different Json strings in question** and there are some diferences in how you parse them, first Example is for `{"page_1": {...}}` case and 2-nd is for `{"page_1": "..."}` Both code samples work fine for me [ImageDemo](https://i.gyazo.com/660c1de02f999747d0519fe195e60f21.png)

Comment: @varren ok, fair enough.

Comment: Still my issue is not resolved.If i try like this  String page_1Str = JSON; 
   JSONObject page_1 = new JSONObject(page_1Str);
      String city = page_1.getString("city");
      System.out.println(city); then also I get error .city is not found